Does inserting new data into a sorted clustered columnstore index in SQL Server disrupt the order?
I'm working with clustered columnstore indexes in SQL Server and have a question about maintaining data order.
I understand that by default, clustered columnstore indexes don't sort data. I've seen a technique where people:

Create a clustered rowstore index to sort the data
Then use the DROP_EXISTING option to create a clustered columnstore index This results in a clustered columnstore index with initially sorted data.

However, I'm concerned about what happens when new data is inserted.
My questions are:

Does inserting new data into this table disrupt the existing order?
If so, are there any ways to prevent this or maintain the order over time?

I'd appreciate insights from anyone who has experience with this scenario or knowledge about the internal workings of columnstore indexes in SQL Server. Thanks in advance for your help!

Could you confirm that your goal is Segment elimination https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-query-performance?view=sql-server-ver16#segment-elimination

No, I'm not talking about Segment elimination.

@SergeyA, if you are not concerned about segment elimination, why are you concerned about existing order?

@DanGuzman I'm still learning this topic and the question pops up when I saw people use this trick to make the data sorted.

First of all you don't need an order, what you actually need is aligned (not overlapping) min and max values for one field in the table so SQL server could perform segment elimination without actually open it and the way to achieve it is sort content of clustered columnstore index.

Does inserting new data into this table disrupt the existing order?

Yes it does.
There are two modes in inserting data - big batches where insert is going directly to rowgroup and small (or even single row) insert so insert is going to deltastore.
As soon as deltastore reached the threshold is moved to closed state and tuple mover convert it to rowgroup. This rowgroup could have min and max values not aligned so it will be scanned every time.
Also tuple mover could combine small rowgroups to biger one, modifying min and max value so this rowgroup won't be eliminated.
Not only insert disrupt order. Update is implemented as delete+insert to deltastore so it will do the same.

If so, are there any ways to prevent this or maintain the order over
time?

You cannot prevent it, but if you think of index rebuild to restore sorted order you are wrong.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#rebuild--with--rebuild_index_option---n---
For columnstore indexes, the REBUILD operation:
  * Doesn't use the sort order.

The only way to actually sort the data is the trick you described.
In SQL 2022 there is an option ORDER that should help sql server to maintain the order, I didn't have a chance to test it however there were complains.
What else could you do?
You can split the table to static and active partition and don't touch static partition at all.
You can use partitioning views to union all static and active tables.
Using this approach you can mix columnstore and rowstore tables, you can create different indexes for active tables and read only ones.
What strategy should you use for maintenance?
Microsoft do not give you any measures of not aligned segments.
The only metric they provide is fragmentation
 100.0*(ISNULL(deleted_rows,0))/NULLIF(total_rows,0)

I wish I had 'best practice' for columnstore index rebuild or reorganize.
